# how can we add a doctype using javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to add doctype using javascript. when a doctype already exist i am able to modify it. but when it is null, not able to add new doctype.. how can i do it in JS

Comment: look : http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/167854-dynamically-changing-doctype

Comment: Though this is not an answer, please remember that doctypes don't change the parsing mode. Whether or not the page is parsed as HTML is determined by the MIME type (`text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`); believe it or not, most "XHTML" pages are sent with the wrong content type and are *actually* parsed as HTML, using the HTML parser. http://azabani.com/articles/markup and http://azabani.com/articles/xhtml have a little more info on this.

Comment: Could you tell us why you would want to?

Answer (score 1):

It is totally useless to add the doctype using JavaScript as the doctype will already have been decided before JavaScript gets a chance to add it to the page. Editing or adding a doctype using JavaScript will not cause the page to be rendered using the JavaScript-generated doctype.